# How to create dataframe from Dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, flask, request

```
 @app.route('/patient')
    def patientData():
        global patientData
        patientGuid = request.args.to_dict()
        df1 = pd.DataFrame([patientGuid])
        #df1.to_csv("path.csv")
        return str(df1)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

But when save file it gives me output in single row json

```
[ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923 } ]
```

But i want save like this

```
PatientGuid   Gender   YearOfBirth
  0              1          1923
```

When give columns name

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([patientGuid],columns=['PatientGuid','Gender','YearOfBirth'])
```

this save csv with only column names.

Comment: can you show us output of `print(patientGuid)` ?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar   {'[ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923} ]': ''}

Answer (score 1):

I think you need,

```
 a=[ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923 } ]
 df=pd.DataFrame(a)
 print(df)
 [out]:
    Gender  PatientGuid YearOfBirth
 0   1          0         1923
```

if you want to change the column names,

```
 df.columns=["a","b","c"]
 print(df)
    a   b   c
0   1   0   1923
```

Comment: not working 1.it gives scalar values error then is pass ,index=[0] it execute but give output like [ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923 } ]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need if get:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

what means there is only `dict`:

```
d = {"PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923}
df = pd.DataFrame([d]).rename(columns={'PatientGuid':'a','Gender':'b','YearOfBirth':'c'})
print (df)
   b  a     c
0  1  0  1923
```

But if add `columns` parameter to `DataFrame` constructor get `NaN`s row, because no align:

```
d = {"PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923}
df = pd.DataFrame([d], columns=['a','b','c'])
print (df)
    a   b   c
0 NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: when i save this DF it look like json [ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923 } ]

Comment: What is `print (type(patientGuid))` ?

Comment: But then another `pyd` answer should working nice, if is possible use `df=pd.DataFrame(a)`

Comment: type(patientGuid) is dict

Comment: yes, but then dont understand, why another solution does not work ;)

Comment: normaly it work pd.DataFrame([d]) but when i run same in flask it just create json like output in csv

Comment: Maybe there is problem `return str(df1)` - need ` return df1` ? If check `print (df)` before save to csv, it is correct?

Comment: when i print type it shows pandas.core.frame.DataFrame but output look like            [ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923}]

Comment: Do you think output of `print (df1)` ? It is not correct? Or output in file?

Comment: i want output in dataframe output is correct but not in DF format                                                                   
    Gender  PatientGuid YearOfBirth
 0    1            0                     1923

Comment: Ok, so what is `print (df1.to_dict())` ? Problem is correct DataFrame is incorrect written to file?

Comment: {'[ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923 } ]': {0: ['']}}

Comment: And what is `print(patientGuid)` ? It is weird.

Comment: [ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923}]

Comment: but how then `print(type(patientGuid))` is dict?

Comment: it should be string or list, not dict.

Comment: doing like this  patientGuid = request.args.to_dict()

Comment: It is no problem, but `[ { "PatientGuid": "0", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923}] ` is not dict. It seems list of dict, but it seems not, because failed all solutions.

Comment: thank you solved , requesting data as string then converting into DF

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
appended_data = []

a=[ { "PatientGuid": "1", "Gender": 1, "YearOfBirth": 1923 },{ "PatientGuid": "3", "Gender": 2, "YearOfBirth": 1922 } ]

for i in a:
    import json
    j=json.dumps(i)
    loaded_j = json.loads(j)

    row = pd.DataFrame([loaded_j], columns=['PatientGuid', 'Gender', 'YearOfBirth'])
    appended_data.append(row)


appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=0)
print(appended_data)
print(appended_data.columns)
appended_data.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

This will help you for sure. (my first Answer :D )